# Error: In assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same

Tags: matlab

I'm stuck on K2 as it brought up this error:

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
>    I must be the same.

I ran the debugger and I found out that `J4` alone was a vector while other variables were all scalar.

How can I resolve this error to have the plot?

Here is the code that I ran.

```
h1 = 1*10^-6;
h2 = (10:10:1500)*10^-6;
a = 62.5*10^-6;
b = a+h1;
c = b+h2;
alpha_1 = 0.55*10^-6;
alpha_2 = 17.2*10^-6;
alpha_3 = 14.2*10^-6;
zeta = 6.3*10^-6;
P11 = 0.121; 
P12 = 0.27;
neff = 1.456;
U1 = 0.17;
U2 = 0.32;
U3 = 0.31;
E1 = 0.74*10^11;
E2 = 1.08*10^11;
E3 = 1.96*10^11;
n = 1;
while(n<=150)
J1(n) = E2*(b^2-a^2)*(1-U1)-E1*a^2*(1-U2)-E1*b^2*(1+U2);
J2(n) = 2*E1*b^2;
J3(n) = E1*E2*(b^2-a^2)*(alpha_2 - alpha_1);
J4(n) = 2*E3*(c(n)^2-b^2)*a^2;
J5(n) = E2*(b^2-a^2)*(1-U3)*b^2+E2*(b^2-a^2)*(1+U3)*c(n)^2-E3*(c(n)^2-b^2)*(1+U2)*a^2-E3*(c(n)^2-b^2)*(1-U2)*b^2;
J6(n) = E2*E3*(c(n)^2 - b^2)*(b^2-a^2)*(alpha_2-alpha_3);

K1(n) = ((alpha_3-alpha_1)*E3*(c(n)^2-b^2)+(alpha_2-alpha_1)*E2*(b^2-a^2))/(E1*a^2+E2*(b^2-a^2)+E3*(c(n)^2-b^2));
K2(n) = (J2*J6-J3*J5)/(J2*J4-J1*J5);

Sr(n) = (neff^2/2)*(P11+P12)*(((1-U1)*K2/E1)-U1*K1);
Sz(n) = (1+P12)*(K1-(2*U2*K2/E1));
St(n) = alpha_1+zeta;
Km(n) = St+Sz+Sr;

n=n+1;
end
plot(h2,Km)
```

Comment: I don't believe you... J1, ... J4, J5, J6 are all the same size, either scalar or vector.  In `(J2*J6-J3*J5)/(J2*J4-J1*J5)` are you trying to have vector products, or did you mean `J2(n)*J6(n)` and so on?  For a dot product, you need to multiply a row vector by a column vector.

Comment: Not part of the problem but maybe try with `for (n = 1:150)` so you do not need a counter? You may also want to think of if `Sr, Sz,St` is supposed to accumulate. Else, use `Km(n) = St(n)+Sz(n)+Sr(n);` (or simply do the full addtion outside the loop.). Btw, I like it when people defines their constants properly. It makes it much more readable than having digits in the equations.

Comment: Thank you guys for your contributions and help. They are very much appreciated. I'm grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To recap what was already said in one answer, here's how I would modify the code:

```
h1 = 1e-6;
h2 = (10:10:1500)*1e-6;
a = 62.5*1e-6;
b = a+h1;
c = b+h2;
alpha_1 = 0.55*1e-6;
alpha_2 = 17.2*1e-6;
alpha_3 = 14.2*1e-6;
zeta = 6.3*1e-6;
P11 = 0.121; 
P12 = 0.27;
neff = 1.456;
U1 = 0.17;
U2 = 0.32;
U3 = 0.31;
E1 = 0.74*1e11;
E2 = 1.08*1e11;
E3 = 1.96*1e11;

% pre-allocate variables
J1 = zeros(size(h2));
J2 = zeros(size(h2));
J3 = zeros(size(h2));
J4 = zeros(size(h2));
J5 = zeros(size(h2));
J6 = zeros(size(h2));
K1 = zeros(size(h2));
K2 = zeros(size(h2));
Sr = zeros(size(h2));
Sz = zeros(size(h2));

for n=1:length(h2)
    J1(n) = E2*(b^2-a^2)*(1-U1)-E1*a^2*(1-U2)-E1*b^2*(1+U2);
    J2(n) = 2*E1*b^2;
    J3(n) = E1*E2*(b^2-a^2)*(alpha_2 - alpha_1);
    J4(n) = 2*E3*(c(n)^2-b^2)*a^2;
    J5(n) = E2*(b^2-a^2)*(1-U3)*b^2+E2*(b^2-a^2)*(1+U3)*c(n)^2-E3*(c(n)^2-b^2)*(1+U2)*a^2-E3*(c(n)^2-b^2)*(1-U2)*b^2;
    J6(n) = E2*E3*(c(n)^2 - b^2)*(b^2-a^2)*(alpha_2-alpha_3);

    K1(n) = ((alpha_3-alpha_1)*E3*(c(n)^2-b^2)+(alpha_2-alpha_1)*E2*(b^2-a^2))/(E1*a^2+E2*(b^2-a^2)+E3*(c(n)^2-b^2));
    K2(n) = (J2(n)*J6(n)-J3(n)*J5(n))/(J2(n)*J4(n)-J1(n)*J5(n));

    Sr(n) = (neff^2/2)*(P11+P12)*(((1-U1)*K2(n)/E1)-U1*K1(n));
    Sz(n) = (1+P12)*(K1(n)-(2*U2*K2(n)/E1));

end    

St = alpha_1+zeta;    
Km = Sz+Sr+St;

plot(h2,Km)
```

**Notes:**

- I have used a `for` loop to ensure the vector lengths are consistent with `h2`
- I have pre-allocated the variables for speed
- I have added various `(n)` to `K1`, `K2`, `J1`, `J2`, etc... in the equations to have only scalar operations
- I have moved stuff out of the `for` loop that didn't need to be there

This gives the following plot (in Octave)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @am304 for this great effort. This is exactly the plot I'm trying to achieve. I quite appreciate this.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: This is huge and you've made my weekend. How about when when I want to achieve same plot but with different values of 'h1 (h1=1:12)*1e-6'

Comment: Hi @am304 Many thank you for your previous support. Please I would to analyse the variation trends of the of temperature sensitivity vs other material parameters(E1vsKm, U1vsKm, alpha_1 vs Km) I tried using similar syntax you used but I'm get this error ???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
 I must be the same.

Error in ==> TempSenPoisson at 39
        J1(n) = E2*(b^2-a^2)*(1-U1)-E1*a^2*(1-U2)-E1*b^2*(1+U2); I would appreciate if you can help me out with at least one of these variations. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and I found out that the dimensions of the vectors used to compute `K2` are not compatible, e.g. each of `J2` and `J6` is a 1-row by 2-columns vector and you cannot multiply those. This also applies for the other multiplications. Depending on what you want to compute, you should transpose either one of them in each multiplication.

FYI: `J.'` is the transposed version of `J` in MATLAB.

[image: workspace]]

Comment: Thanks Man for your effort, I quite appreciate your contribution and I've been able to sort it out. Cheers

Comment: @Comsol If this helped you, accept it as an answwer